# Using managed beans and injection in a J2EE application in Websphere Liberty Profile

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, managed-bean, websphere-liberty

I've got a J2EE app I'm converting to run on Websphere Liberty Profile (WLP).  I'm specifically trying to get my EJB references injected.

I've got my WLP server configured with the ejb-lite, managed-beans, and cdi features.  I've placed a beans.xml file in my WEB-INF directory, and annotated an action class as a @ManagedBean, and added a @PostConstruct and @PreRemove method with logging to see if things are working.  I never see my @PostConstruct and @PreRemove methods called

I've tried a few things to get the injection to work, including @Inject and various flavors of @EJB with different arguments.  Nothing seems to work.  I don't get any errors, but there's no indication that any annotation processing is taking place.  When I do a straight JNDI lookup to get the ejb, it works fine.

Everything I've read indicates that this *should* work, but I can't figure out why it doesn't.

Comment: My guess is that your JSF managed bean isn't really being treated as a JSF managed bean, or you aren't getting to it in a container-provided way -- so it doesn't get injection services.  I would focus on that aspect.

Comment: I'm not using JSF, I'm trying to use the managed-beans/CDI capability of J2EE 6.  However, after a lot of experimentation, I think you're right.

Answer (score 1):

@covener was correct...the bean creation wasn't happening via the container in the way I thought, so no dependency injection was taking place.  I was misled by the fact that I would *sometimes* get errors from the container if I made an mistake in my annotation for the the @Inject or @EJB tags.  That told me that the classes were being scanned and processed, it was only happening as part of a preprocess step by the openwebbeans container in WebSphere Liberty Profile.  All of the docs I could find online were pretty vague about the requirements, but I think the key is your class has to be created directly by the container, instead of created by a class created by the container.

So even though my classes are correctly annotated, and are actually being processed for annotations by the container, the circumstances of my app are such that the classes aren't created in a managed way by the container (and in fact can't be), so they never get handled for CDI.

Answer (score 0):

`@ManagedBean` is a JSF annotation you shouldn't use in CDI context. Your bean class should be concrete, have no constructor or a default constructor with no parameter.
`@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy`(not `@PreRemove`) should be put on method with no arguments.
If your problem persist try to update your question with more information (class, server log, etc...)

Comment: No, it's a J2EE 6 thing: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/ManagedBean.html.  confusingly, it's *also* a JSF annotation, but I'm trying to use the managed beans capability of WebSphere 8.5 Liberty Profile.

Comment: This annotation is useless as stated here http://germanescobar.net/2010/04/4-areas-of-possible-confusion-in-jee6.html
Now it shouldn't prevent CDI to work. If you want more help you'll have to share code.